# How do I convert [*] into a regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression, wildcards

Essentially I need to Ctrl+f (search for) the following string...

[*]

This means that I want to find everything that matches between (and including) the brackets. What do I substitute the "*" for in order to create a regular expression?

Comment: What is the program you are searching with?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
\[.*\]
```

Explanation:

`\[` Matches the character " [ ". It needs to be escaped by a backslash, because it has a special meaning in regular expressions.

`.*` Matches any set of characters (`.` for a single character and `*` for any number of times)

`\]` Matches the character " ] "

Comment: Note that `.*` matches any string, so your regular expression would match `[*]`, but also `[hello]` and `[*] [*]`.